# How to convert string to uppercase in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following piece in my CloudFormation template

```
 PublicSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.1.10.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]    # Get the first AZ in the list        
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub
          - ${AWS::StackName}-PUB-${SUFFIX}
          - SUFFIX: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]
```

I need SUFFIX to be in uppercase, how do I do it?

Comment: I saw the note, but can't have it working for my case. It keeps saying a template validation error

Comment: When I try to chain the functions it give the following error ."..intrinsic functions in transform block must only contain parameter values or stack metadata."

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the [transform intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-transform.html) that calls a macro. Somebody has already written a bunch on string manipulation macros so if you deployed them you could use them with no extra coding.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions

Comment: Transform seems not to support functions as parameters. It does not work for my case

Comment: I'm sure I've done this at work, if I get chance I'll check when I'm back in tomorrow.

Comment: It's not clear from the README posted, but you need to add that Python file as a transform function rather than just using the upper function. CF doesn't have any built-in support for this and you need to add your own transform function to do it.